# Помогите пожалуйста нежен асинхронный таймер на питоне чтобы его не останавливал input и при каждом ответы нет - 1 милисикунда (таймер в начале 10 с.)

Tags: python

```
tired = False

while step < 100:
      answer = input ('ноги не отвалились?')
      if answer == 'нет' :
            step += 1
            print ('ты прошёл: ', step)
      elif answer ==  'да' :
            print('ты проиграл')
            break

if step == 100:
      print('Поздравляю ты потратил жизнь зря!')
```

Comment: в начале забыл step = 0

Comment: Сигалярм можно, но я его не люблю